# RowSetFactory implementation subclass

Tags: java, jdbc

How we are able to create the instance of RowSetFactory interface using RowSetProvider class?

```
RowSetFactory rsfactory=RowSetProvider.newFactory();
```

What is the implementation subclass of RowSetFactory interface and in which package it is available?

Comment: Why do you care? It's just yet another instance of the factory pattern in the JDK. There are hundreds of them. What the implementation class is is NOYB.

Comment: I dont know I can't move on without caring bout.

Comment: That doesn't actually answer my question. Why do you think yo can't move on? The name of the implementation class isn't going to make any difference to your coding. At least it shouldn't, and if it does you're doing it wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The implementation class depends on the service implementations available on the classpath (and in the order they are found). This is documented in [`RowSetProvider.newFactory()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/sql/rowset/RowSetProvider.html#newFactory--):

> Creates a new instance of a `RowSetFactory` implementation. This method uses the following look up order to determine the RowSetFactory implementation class to load:
>
> - The System property `javax.sql.rowset.RowSetFactory`. For example:
>
>   ```
>   -Djavax.sql.rowset.RowSetFactory=com.sun.rowset.RowSetFactoryImpl
>   ```
> - The `ServiceLoader` API. The `ServiceLoader` API will look for a class name in the file `META-INF/services/javax.sql.rowset.RowSetFactory` in jars available to the runtime. For example, to have the the `RowSetFactory` implementation `com.sun.rowset.RowSetFactoryImpl` loaded, the entry in `META-INF/services/javax.sql.rowset.RowSetFactory` would be:
>
>   ```
>   com.sun.rowset.RowSetFactoryImpl
>   ```
> - Platform default `RowSetFactory` instance.

If there are multiple implementations on the classpath and you want to specify which implementation to load, then you can use [`newFactory(String factoryClassName, ClassLoader cl)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/sql/rowset/RowSetProvider.html#newFactory-java.lang.String-java.lang.ClassLoader-).